# How to get the icon of other applications (Android)

Tags: java, android

What I'm doing is getting a list of all the current running processes on the phone. Which I have done by,

```
private List<RunningAppProcessInfo> process;
private ActivityManager activityMan;
...
activityMan = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
process = activityMan.getRunningAppProcesses();
```

this works fine. When I call the processName field like

```
process.get(i).processName;
```

I get a name like com.android.mail for example.

what I'm trying to do is use this to get access to that application so I can display its icon to the user, but I cant find anything that lets me do this. Is there something that can help me?

I'm testing this app on my hero so the api level is 3 (android 1.5).

Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

Ok, I figured out how to do it. In case your curious this is what I did.

```
private PackageManager pk;
pk = getPackageManager();
....
pk.getApplicationIcon(process.get(i).processName)
```

Thanks.

Comment: It is wrong to use the process name -- that will sometimes happen to be right, but not always.  You need to use the package name.

Answer (score 0):

try this way make a class called packageinformation:

public class PackageInformation{

```
private Context mContext;

public  PackageInformation(Context context){
    mContext=context;   
}


class InfoObject {
public String appname = "";
public String pname = "";
public String versionName = "";
public int versionCode = 0;
public Drawable icon;


public void InfoObjectAggregatePrint() {//not used yet
    Log.v(appname,appname + "\t" + pname + "\t" + versionName + "\t" + versionCode);
}
```

}
       private ArrayList getPackages() {
         ArrayList apps = getInstalledApps(false); /* false = no system packages */
    final int max = apps.size();
    for (int i=0; i

```
 public ArrayList<InfoObject> getInstalledApps(boolean getSysPackages) {
ArrayList<InfoObject> res = new ArrayList<InfoObject>();        
List<PackageInfo> packs = mContext.getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
for(int i=0;i<packs.size();i++) {
    PackageInfo p = packs.get(i);
    if ((!getSysPackages) && (p.versionName == null)) {
        continue ;
    }
    InfoObject newInfo = new InfoObject();
    newInfo.appname = p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(mContext.getPackageManager()).toString();
    newInfo.pname = p.packageName;
    newInfo.versionName = p.versionName;
    newInfo.versionCode = p.versionCode;
    newInfo.icon = p.applicationInfo.loadIcon(mContext.getPackageManager());
    res.add(newInfo);
}
return res; 
 }


 }
```

tuck this away somewhere and now to access the info from your working class do this:

```
  PackageInformation androidPackagesInfo=new PackageInformation(this);      
    ArrayList<InfoObject> appsData=androidPackagesInfo.getInstalledApps(true);


for (InfoObject info : appsData) {


            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, info.appname,2).show();
                Drawable somedrawable=info.icon;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Since Android 3.0 you might want to get a bigger launcher icon that you can't get the way you described. If so, perhaps my answer to question below can help you: [Getting App Icon in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600740/getting-app-icon-in-android/16279240#16279240)

Answer (score 0):

While packagemanager.getApplicationIcon(pkagename) works for some apps but not for all.

Found better answer here:
[how to get running applications icon on android programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15567957/how-to-get-running-applications-icon-on-android-programmatically)

Uses:

```
Drawable ico=getApplicationInfo(packagemanager,PackageManager.GET_META_DATA).loadIcon(getPackageManager());
```