# Getting App Icon in Android

Tags: android

I'm having some trouble retrieving icons for installed Android App. The following code returns icons for all apps, however, some apps are returned with small icons (perhaps from drawable - ldpi folder) while some with large icons.

```
List<PackageInfo> package = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);

for(PackageInfo p : package){
    iApp.icon = p.applicationInfo.loadIcon(getPackageManager()); 
}
```

How Can I get icons which are all of the same size, just like in Manage Application section of Android?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Apps might just have different sized icons.  The Android Settings app loads icons just like you.  It scales the icons when displaying them.

Here's a snippet from packages/apps/Settings/res/layout/manage_applications_item.xml:

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/app_icon"
    android:layout_width="@android:dimen/app_icon_size"
    android:layout_height="@android:dimen/app_icon_size"
    android:layout_marginRight="11dip"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>
```

Comment: can you elaborate , i have same issue

Comment: however, in standard launcher list of apps (not list of apps in "manage applications" display in settings) you see beautiful big icons (on pad) unlike blurry icons that were scaled up the way you described. There must be some other way :-(

Answer (score 22):

I want to add something to previous answer what applies to Android 3.0 and greater.

You can notice that icons retrieved in this standard way (i mean applicationInfo.loadIcon and other typical methods) are smaller than icons you see in launcher app. Scale up just makes icons blurrier. If you want big icons you can use next code (i took it from launcher source code you can find [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.2.2_r1/com/android/launcher2/IconCache.java#IconCache) and changed a bit). Pay your attention to `activityManager.getLauncherLargeIconDensity` method.

```
public Drawable getFullResDefaultActivityIcon() {
    return getFullResIcon(Resources.getSystem(), android.R.mipmap.sym_def_app_icon);
}

public Drawable getFullResIcon(Resources resources, int iconId) {
    Drawable d;
    try {
        ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        int iconDpi = activityManager.getLauncherLargeIconDensity();
        d = resources.getDrawableForDensity(iconId, iconDpi);
    } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
        d = null;
    }

    return (d != null) ? d : getFullResDefaultActivityIcon();
}

public Drawable getFullResIcon(String packageName, int iconId) {
    Resources resources;
    try {
        resources = mContext.getPackageManager().getResourcesForApplication(packageName);
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        resources = null;
    }
    if (resources != null) {
        if (iconId != 0) {
            return getFullResIcon(resources, iconId);
        }
    }
    return getFullResDefaultActivityIcon();
}

public Drawable getFullResIcon(ResolveInfo info) {
    return getFullResIcon(info.activityInfo);
}

public Drawable getFullResIcon(ActivityInfo info) {
    Resources resources;
    try {
        resources = mContext.getPackageManager().getResourcesForApplication(info.applicationInfo);
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        resources = null;
    }
    if (resources != null) {
        int iconId = info.getIconResource();
        if (iconId != 0) {
            return getFullResIcon(resources, iconId);
        }
    }
    return getFullResDefaultActivityIcon();
}

private Drawable getAppIcon(ResolveInfo info) {
    return getFullResIcon(info.activityInfo);
}
```

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: getFullResIcon(Resources....) is just what i need!! This answer is more precise..i can get the biggest icon supplied then can scale it as my needs. +1 @Andrei

Comment: `getDrawableForDensity(int id, int density)` was added in api level 15... Anything below that?

Answer (score 11):

Although, this has been answered a long time back, here is the complete function. Hope it will help others.

To get the icon, you should query for icon for different dpi.

Try this:

```
public static Drawable getIconFromPackageName(String packageName, Context context)
    {
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1)
        {
            try
            {
                PackageInfo pi = pm.getPackageInfo(packageName, 0);
                Context otherAppCtx = context.createPackageContext(packageName, Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);

                int displayMetrics[] = {DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH, DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH, DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_TV};

                for (int displayMetric : displayMetrics)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Drawable d = otherAppCtx.getResources().getDrawableForDensity(pi.applicationInfo.icon, displayMetric);
                        if (d != null)
                        {
                            return d;
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Resources.NotFoundException e)
                    {
//                      Log.d(TAG, "NameNotFound for" + packageName + " @ density: " + displayMetric);
                        continue;
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // Handle Error here
            }
        }

        ApplicationInfo appInfo = null;
        try
        {
            appInfo = pm.getApplicationInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
        }
        catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return appInfo.loadIcon(pm);
    }
```

Comment: `getDrawableForDensity(int id, int density)` was added in api level 15... Anything below that?

Comment: Useful for getting the original, unthemed icon

Answer (score 1):

You must define in App class ;

```
private Drawable appIcon; 

public Drawable getappIcon(){
        return this.appIcon;
    }
```

if you use RecyclerViewAdapter ;

```
   List<App> list_app;

    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.appIcon.setImageDrawable(list_app.get(position).getappIcon());

    }
```

in MainActivity ;

```
private List<App> appList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

        appList = new ArrayList<App>();

        for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
          Drawable drawableIcon =packageInfo.loadIcon(getPackageManager());
          appList.add(new App (drawableIcon));

        }
```