# Default Settings launcher icon

Tags: android

I'm at a loss trying to find the default icon used for the Settings application launcher under **\android-sdk\platforms\android-10\data\res\drawable-mdpi**\

What name does this icon have? can I use it in my application? here it is:

- 2.2:

[image: 2.2]

- 4.0:

[image: 4.0]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you're looking for a "settings" button for your app, you can include the system icon in your xml using `@android:drawable/ic_menu_preferences`. It won't get you the nice, colored version you included above, but makes a perfect settings icon in your menu or ActionBar.

Comment: Thank you, I'd seen some information about the ic_menu_preferences icon, but I want the nice looking icon from my screenshots. Where does that one come from?

Comment: I found the ICS version in my android-sdk folder, under /docs/resources/samples/ApiDemos/res/drawable-*dpi.

Comment: Indeed, the ic_launcher_settings can be found at the specified location. I was hoping I'd find it among the android resources. I guess the answer is that this isn't possible. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I described way you can retrieve full resolution icon of every app installed on your phone/pad here: [Getting App Icon in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600740/getting-app-icon-in-android/16279240#16279240).

So all you need is find package name of this app.

It's not as simple as retrieving standard android icon from android resources, but however it can help you.