# Get Application Icon Id - Monodroid

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I need to get the int id of my application icon. Is there any way I can do this?

I'm aware that there's GetApplicationIcon in PackageManager, but this returns a drawable. How can I get the Id of the drawable?

```
Drawable drawable = ApplicationContext.PackageManager.GetApplicationIcon(applicationInfo);
```

I was thinking of looping through all the resources in Android, but I'm not sure how, and I think it would be expensive. Any efficient way I can get the icon id?

EDIT: I understand that I can just easily get the resource id from R.drawable.myicon, but I was hoping to get the Id with the use of PackageManager or ApplicationContext.Resources.

EDIT #2: I got it. See my answer below.

Comment: Check: [Getting App Icon in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600740/getting-app-icon-in-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I got it.

```
Intent intent = context.PackageManager.GetLaunchIntentForPackage(context.PackageName);
ResolveInfo resolveInfo = context.PackageManager.ResolveActivity(intent, PackageInfoFlags.MatchDefaultOnly);
int appIcon = resolveInfo.IconResource;
```

Answer (score 3):

`R.drawable.ic_launcher` (or other name you gave it) should represent the id you need.

Answer (score 1):

Well, since it's *your* application, you can just look in your manifest. Your icon appears in the `<application>` tag, in the `android:icon` attribute. Just look at that file and see what it says.

You don't need to program that, just do it yourself one time.