# getting Icons of applications running on device

Tags: android, listview, icons

I have a list activity which display all running applications in the device. it's displaying a default icon for all application . but I need to get actual application Icon for each application in the list.

```
public class ApplicationList extends ListActivity {
DataHelper dh;
ImageView vi;
private Drawable icon;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.applist);
    dh = new DataHelper(getApplicationContext());

    PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

    Log.d("Test1", "INSERTING APP LIST TO SERVER DB");
     List<ResolveInfo> list = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
     ArrayList<String> applist = new ArrayList<String>();

     for(ResolveInfo rInfo: list){

        applist.add(rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString() );
    }


    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.installedapp, R.id.textView1, applist);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

[How to get the icon of other applications (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384713/how-to-get-the-icon-of-other-applications-android)
I tried this link but I did not get things solved. so can any one help me out. thanks!

Comment: see this maybe helpfull[Get installed Applications with Name, Package Name, Version and Icon](http://www.androidsnippets.com/get-installed-applications-with-name-package-name-version-and-icon)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try like this

```
List<PackageInfo> packs = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
 Drawable[] icons=new Drawable[packs.size];
for(int i=0;i<packs.size();i++) {
    PackageInfo p = packs.get(i);
    icons[i]= p.applicationInfo.loadIcon(getPackageManager());
 }
```

Comment: I tried it out but instead of getting icon I am getting android.graphics.draw able.bitmapdrawable@40547e70  like this

Comment: You can convert it to bitmap and then display...Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)d).getBitmap();like this.. where d is drawable.

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
Icon icon = p.applicationInfo.loadIcon(getPackageManager());
imageView.setImageDrawable(icon);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way make a class called packageinformation:

public class PackageInformation{

```
private Context mContext;

public  PackageInformation(Context context){
    mContext=context;   
}


class InfoObject {
public String appname = "";
public String pname = "";
public String versionName = "";
public int versionCode = 0;
public Drawable icon;


public void InfoObjectAggregatePrint() {//not used yet
    Log.v(appname,appname + "\t" + pname + "\t" + versionName + "\t" + versionCode);
}
```

}
       private ArrayList getPackages() {
         ArrayList apps = getInstalledApps(false); /* false = no system packages */
    final int max = apps.size();
    for (int i=0; i

```
 public ArrayList<InfoObject> getInstalledApps(boolean getSysPackages) {
ArrayList<InfoObject> res = new ArrayList<InfoObject>();        
List<PackageInfo> packs = mContext.getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
for(int i=0;i<packs.size();i++) {
    PackageInfo p = packs.get(i);
    if ((!getSysPackages) && (p.versionName == null)) {
        continue ;
    }
    InfoObject newInfo = new InfoObject();
    newInfo.appname = p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(mContext.getPackageManager()).toString();
    newInfo.pname = p.packageName;
    newInfo.versionName = p.versionName;
    newInfo.versionCode = p.versionCode;
    newInfo.icon = p.applicationInfo.loadIcon(mContext.getPackageManager());
    res.add(newInfo);
}
return res; 
 }


 }
```

tuck this away somewhere and now to access the info from your working Activity class do this:

```
  PackageInformation androidPackagesInfo=new PackageInformation(this);      
    ArrayList<InfoObject> appsData=androidPackagesInfo.getInstalledApps(true);


for (InfoObject info : appsData) {


            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, info.appname,2).show();
                Drawable somedrawable=info.icon;
```

}