# how to get running applications icon on android programmatically

Tags: android

Below here is my code but i am getting default android launcher icon for all running applications:

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();

            ActivityManager am1 = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

            List<RunningTaskInfo> processes = am1.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

                if (processes != null) {
                    for (int k = 0; k < processes.size(); k++) {
                        // String pkgName = app.getPackageName();
                        String packageName = processes.get(k).topActivity
                                .getPackageName();
                        Drawable ico = null;
                        try
                        {
                         String pName = (String) pm.getApplicationLabel(pm
                                .getApplicationInfo(packageName,
                                        PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));

                            ico = pm.getApplicationIcon(pName);

                        } 
                        catch (NameNotFoundException e) 
                        {
                            Log.e("ERROR", "Unable to find icon for package '"
                                    + packageName + "': " + e.getMessage());
                        }
                        icons.put(processes.get(k).topActivity.getPackageName(),ico);
                    }
```

Comment: Please note that getRunningTasks() will never return null, but an empty list at most. Read my answer below.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

just replace this line

```
ico = pm.getApplicationIcon(pName);
```

to this

```
ico = getApplicationInfo().loadIcon(getPackageManager());
```

**EDITED** full code :

```
public void getAllICONS() {

    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();

    ActivityManager am1 = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

    List<RunningTaskInfo> processes = am1
            .getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

    if (processes != null) {
        for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
            // String pkgName = app.getPackageName();
            String packageName = processes.get(k).topActivity
                    .getPackageName();
            Log.e("packageName-->", "" + packageName);
            Drawable ico = null;
            try {
                String pName = (String) pm.getApplicationLabel(pm
                        .getApplicationInfo(packageName,
                                PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));
                name.add("" + pName);
                ApplicationInfo a = pm.getApplicationInfo(packageName,
                        PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
                ico = getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(
                        processes.get(k).topActivity.getPackageName());
                getPackageManager();
                Log.e("ico-->", "" + ico);

            } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
                Log.e("ERROR", "Unable to find icon for package '"
                        + packageName + "': " + e.getMessage());
            }
            // icons.put(processes.get(k).topActivity.getPackageName(),ico);
            icons.add(ico);

        }
    }
}
```

above code is show you icons like:

[image]

Comment: hi @RajivGaikwad: please check this : http://dj-android.blogspot.in/2013/02/multi-selection-listview-android-with.html

Comment: first tell me what type of data you have to delete?? running application?? or any other data (like form sqlite db)??

Comment: then also same process. i think you have checked my code here: http://dj-android.blogspot.in/2013/02/multi-selection-listview-android-with.html ok then you get selected position. m i right?? if yes then on deleted button click item you have to make for loop like for(int i = 0; i < posSel.size(); i++){adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(i)); } after that call notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: In your given solution i have add the checkbox in scanrow1.xml and in activitymain.xml added the kill button .onclick of this button i want to delete these all checked row....Thanks

Comment: i thing you hace created that object in listadaptert a = new listadaptert(this); list.setadapter(a); ok... so use that a.remove(a.getitem(i));

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the app icon, you can use the *[getApplicationIcon()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getApplicationIcon%28java.lang.String%29)* method of the [PackageManger](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html).

In your case, since you are retriving the icon of the running apps, you can do something like:

```
final ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> runningTasks;

try {
    runningTasks = am.getRunningTasks(100);
}
catch ( SecurityException e ) {
    runningTasks = new ArrayList<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo>();
    //e.printStackTrace();
}

Drawable icon;

for ( ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo task : runningTasks ) {
    final String packageName = task.topActivity.getPackageName();

    try {
            icon = pm.getApplicationIcon(packageName);
    }
    catch ( PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e ) {
            //e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Otherwise, even better, you may use the other implementation of *[getApplicationIcon()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getApplicationIcon%28android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo%29)*, thus:

```
ApplicationInfo ai;

try {
    ai = pm.getApplicationInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
} catch ( PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e ) {
    ai = null;
    //e.printStackTrace();
}

if ( ai != null ) {
    icon = pm.getApplicationIcon(ai);
}
```

**PS:** In any case, please note that *[getRunningTasks()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningTasks%28int%29)* will never return **null**, but an **empty list** at most.