# How to create an alert dialog with app icons next to the items(apps)

Tags: android, android-dialog, android-dialogfragment

I have created an alert dialog with a list of apps (in text). So when I click on any of them, that particular app launches. I did this using AlertDialog fragment and using this code:

```
apps = new String[]{"App1","App2","App3"};
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle("Choose the app");
        builder.setItems(apps, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                   // The 'which' argument contains the index position
                   // of the selected item

                      //Code to launch the apps
               }
        });
        return builder.create();
```

Is it possible to display the **app icons** along with the app names? If yes, what changes should I make to the code?

How do I get the **app icons** of *installed apps* on the phone?

Comment: For that you have to make one `Custom Dialog` and inflated(Contains your `ListView`) one view to that `Dialog` then you fetch all the apps info using `RetrievePackages` to one `ArrayList` and Bind to your `ListView` with `Custom Row`

Answer (score 1):

1.Create custom layout for dialog like you want then

**Layout** custom_dialog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#FFF" 
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

2.Make adapter with your text , icon(i.e items object )and your custom layout

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter  = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, R.layout.custom_dialog.xml);
```

3.set this  adapter to your dialog like this

```
  builder.setAdapter(adapter  , new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

           }
    });
```

**Update:**

Best option is to use `listview` in activity with   `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"` so that activity will look like dialog(as u want list of apps in dialog only) and also it will be easy to handle the data in listview compared to dialog with adapter.This will fulfill all your requirement in easy and smart way.

Comment: Would this work if the number of items on the list vary based on some condition? If no, please tell me how to do that.

Comment: I mean to say how to dynamically associate this with the app icons. Would I have define that many app icons and names manually in my layout file?

Comment: you need pass two  things  to your  adapter one is app name and another image of app

Comment: Ok I will try and get back to you

Answer (score 0):

- call your app like this

  ```
   Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.address");
   startActivity(LaunchIntent);
  ```

i got reference from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872063/android-launch-an-application-from-another-application)

- add your icon dynamically like this

  see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15567957/how-to-get-running-applications-icon-on-android-programmatically)

Comment: I know how to launch the app. My question is *how* to include the app icon along with the app names in the dialog fragment list?

Comment: is it dynamic list ??

Comment: yes, a dynamic list of a few fixed apps, that is, amongst the few apps that I am checking for by package name, the ones which are installed will appear on this list.

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a new xml layout, then inflate it using:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view = inflate.inflate(R.layout.your_file, null,false);
```

And then on AlertDialog

```
builder.setView(view)
```

I'd add a list view to layout and then handle it like every other listview. Use view.findViewById to get references.

How get list of apps? http://javatechig.com/android/how-to-get-list-of-installed-apps-in-android