# Get package name of Top Activity in Android L

Tags: android

On older versions the following code works.

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);  
String pkgname = am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getPackageName();
```

It no longer works on Android L. It always returns the package name of the launcher. How can I get it in Android L?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get running applications icon on android programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15567957/how-to-get-running-applications-icon-on-android-programmatically)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps help you :

```
ActivityManager mActivityManager =(ActivityManager)this.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 20){
String mPackageName = mActivityManager.getRunningAppProcesses().get(0).processName;
}
else{
  String mpackageName = mActivityManager.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getPackageName();
}
```

[SEE THIS LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27689352/4813855)

Comment: Thanks you very much.My English is bad.I am afraid that nobody can understand my question.

Comment: Does not work anymore