# how to get running applications icon?

Tags: android, android-icons

**i found this[how to get running applications icon on android programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15567957/how-to-get-running-applications-icon-on-android-programmatically) on  how we show icons and names of running application but idont know what the type of icons.add(ico);and name.add("" + pName); are so can some on help me what should i do to make it run **

```
public void getAllICONS() {

    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();

    ActivityManager am1 = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

    List<RunningTaskInfo> processes = am1
            .getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

    if (processes != null) {
        for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
            // String pkgName = app.getPackageName();
            String packageName = processes.get(k).topActivity
                    .getPackageName();
            Log.e("packageName-->", "" + packageName);
            Drawable ico = null;
            try {
                String pName = (String) pm.getApplicationLabel(pm
                        .getApplicationInfo(packageName,
                                PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));
                name.add("" + pName);
                ApplicationInfo a = pm.getApplicationInfo(packageName,
                        PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
                ico = getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(
                        processes.get(k).topActivity.getPackageName());
                getPackageManager();
                Log.e("ico-->", "" + ico);

            } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
                Log.e("ERROR", "Unable to find icon for package '"
                        + packageName + "': " + e.getMessage());
            }
            // icons.put(processes.get(k).topActivity.getPackageName(),ico);
            icons.add(ico);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: icons and name is not defined