# Display device icons in android app

Tags: android

I want to use the camera and album icons in my app,  just like whatsapp app (when editing the profile picture):

[image]

In order to do it, I'm using these drawables:

- @android:drawable/ic_menu_camera
- @android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery

But the icons don't look the same:

[image]

How can I use the same icons as whatsapp?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384713/how-to-get-the-icon-of-other-applications-android

Comment: Do you have the **copyright** (or any **legal or commercial agreement**) for using **someone else's graphics**?

Comment: No, should I? I thought it's a part of the framework

Comment: ... which framework? Android? No, it's custom graphics. You are correctly using the Android graphics (which, as you noted, **looks different**). OR you  might provide **your** custom graphics. To use **other people's stuff** (including graphics), you must have an **agreement** with them.

Comment: So how the camera & album icons in whatsapp dialog is changing when I change my device icon pack?